# Getting data from multiple temp tables

Tags: sql, join, temp

I have inserted different values into different temp tables. For example Salesman wise sold particular product. Product wise I have inserted to temp table.

But while getting data from temp table with join I am taking reference of first temp table. In case the second salesman is not avail on first temp table am not getting accurate result

Help me to resolve this issue!!!!

Regards

Harikrishnan

Comment: post sample data which might be useful

Comment: post your table field names and desired data

Comment: post your existing query, preferably indicating which is the first and which is the second temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Change your inner join to the first temp table, to be an outer join.